# Wii U cant update - Error 108-0144

Tags: wii-u, mario-kart-8

I have a Wii U with the update version that comes on MK8 - and when I connect to Internet and try to play it - it says I need an update. So I press OK, and then it says I need a system update too. So I say fine, and it not only sits on retrieving data, then when it gives up, it comes up with 108-0144. And my Wii U functions off of the custom settings [here.](http://www.joystiq.com/2012/11/19/how-to-connect-a-stubborn-wii-u-to-wi-fi/)

So I disconnect my Wii U and give up a few times.

Comment: Have you tried the troubleshooting steps listed here: https://www.nintendo.com/consumer/wfc/en_na/ds/results.jsp?error_code=108-0144&system=Wiiu

Comment: Well... Try the update again: The update barely started. Enter an alternate DNS: I already had one. But I'll try the other fixes.

Comment: Everything's been saying the strength is good... Testing my internet now...

Comment: SpeedTest.net gave me an F as in Figures